# php RegEx extract values from string

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

I am new to regular expressions and I am trying to extract some specific values from this string:

> "Iban: EU4320000713864374\r\nSwift: DTEADCCC\r\nreg.no 2361 \r\naccount no. 1234531735"

Values that I am trying to extract:

```
EU4320000713864374

2361
```

This is what I am trying to do now:

```
preg_match('/[^Iban: ](?<iban>.*)[^\\r\\nreg.no ](?<regnr>.*)[^\\r\\n]/',$str,$matches);
```

All I am getting back is null or empty array. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets make no sense, you *perhaps* meant to anchor at the beginning of a line:

```
$result = preg_match(
    '/^Iban: (?<iban>.*)\R.*\R^reg.no (?<regnr>.*)/m'
    , $str, $matches
);
```

This requires to set the multi-line modifier (see `m` at the very end). I also replaced `\r\n` with `\R` so that this handles all kind of line-separator sequences easily.

Example: https://eval.in/47062

A slightly better variant then only captures non-whitespace values:

```
$result = preg_match(
    '/^Iban: (?<iban>\S*)\R.*\R^reg.no (?<regnr>\S*)/m'
    , $str, $matches
);
```

Example: https://eval.in/47069

Result then is (beautified):

```
Array
(
    [0]     => "Iban: EU4320000713864374
Swift: DTEADCCC
reg.no 2361"
    [iban]  => "EU4320000713864374"
    [1]     => "EU4320000713864374"
    [regnr] => "2361"
    [2]     => "2361"
)
```

Comment: @Pavel: See the update. And see my comment about the square brackets. I don't know why you put them there in the first place.

Comment: `preg_match` return `bool`, not **matches**

Comment: @Mpol: It returns `$result` as bool|int (false, 0, 1) *and* `$matches` as byref parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/Iban: (\\S+).*reg.no (\\S+)/s", $str, $matches);
```

There is a specific feature about newlines: dot (.) does not match newline character unless `s` flag is specified.